# Django models FileField large file upload

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I need to upload large files(approximately 1GB) while using FileField field in Django model. This gives the error DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE. I think I need to use chunked-upload while saving in the model. How can I do that? Or is there any other solution?

```
RequestDataTooBig at /admin/supports/software/add/
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8000/admin/supports/software/add/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: RequestDataTooBig
Exception Value:    
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/http/request.py in body, line 297
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app',
 '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Prş, 26 Ağu 2021 15:24:51 +0300
```

my model :

```
class Software(AbstractBasicFTPSupportModel):
category = models.ForeignKey(
    to="SupportCategory", related_name="softwares", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("category"),
)
related_products = models.ManyToManyField(
    "product.Product", blank=True, related_name="softwares", verbose_name=_("related products")
)
software_file = models.FileField(
    upload_to=save_support_file, verbose_name=_("software file"), null=True, blank=True, max_length=255,
)
```

Comment: ```DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE``` Change this to whatever value you want in ```settings.py```. Default is 2.5MB (2621440)

Comment: @Ram I also changed it, but since the file I want to upload is more than 1 GB, increasing the memory size may create a security vulnerability. And when I change it and try, my app closes.

Comment: @ShahnawazIrfan I don't understand you, can you explain?

Comment: You should mention that you are uploading a **1GB** file in the question so that people will know what size you are dealing with

Comment: @Ram Yes, you are right. I am editinq the question.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might also want to explore using storage providers e.g. AWS S3 and then just store in your database the URLs to the files. That way, you don't have to worry about file sizes nor uploading mechanism since that will be handled by the provider.

Comment: Actually I use this structure to store my files in google cloud storage. After transferring the uploaded file to the cloud, I delete it from my application. It is very stable in small sizes, but there is a problem at high sizes.@NielGodfreyPonciano

Comment: If you are already using GCP, you might want to explore options to directly upload a file to the bucket without your Django app in the middle. As reference, AWS S3 provides this functionality by generating keys and then using those keys to directly upload the file to AWS S3, no need of the intermediate Django app. [Here is how it's done in Python.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html#generating-a-presigned-url-to-upload-a-file). Maybe there's a similar way in GCP, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

set FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE in settings.py

Comment: I tried, but this is not the solution for me, the error I get is very different. I'm editing the question, you can check it out.